# Sonata Project - How to display blocks in Symfony 2 views

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata

How to display blocks created in Sonata Admin Panel in my view ? 
I created blocks like in http://demo.sonata-project.org/ . Firstly I created sonata.page.block.container, sonata.block.service.text  and set that block.container is parent of service.text. But i cant find out how to display data from sonata.block.service.text on my page.
Thank's for any advice or example !

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a Sonata page, you need to add it through the BO (edit the page, add block, and so on). The process is documented there: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/page/master/doc/reference/getting_started.html#add-or-edit-a-block

However, if you want to display a block from a twig template, you may use the Twig helpers documented there: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/block/master/doc/reference/twig_helpers.html